# C++ string/char and accents

Tags: c++, string, char, non-ascii-characters

I'm writing a text writer in C++, which I'll have a string of a phrase and display the appropriate bitmap font for each char value.

For now, it's working for the regular characters, but I'm getting weird values for accents and other characters such as À, Á, Â, Ã, etc

I'm doing this:

```
int charToPrint = 'a';
//use this value to figure which bitmap font to display
```

The bitmap font does have these characters, but on this line I'm not getting the values I'm supposed to get, such as: 195 for **Ã**, 199 for **Ç**, etc...

I tried changing my project's character set from Multi Byte to Unicode, but I don't think that does anything for the char->int conversion...

How can I get this conversion with chars?

**Edit:** I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7, and it's an OpenGL application with a bitmap font.
I've mapped the positions/width/height of each character, according to it's **char** value, so the character **a** is at the position 97 of my bitmap font (plus width accounted for).

To draw, I just need to figure the position based on the char code.

I have a string of a phrase I want to display, and I loop through each character, figure the charCode, and call my draw function.

For these characters with accents, I'm getting negative values, so my draw function doesn't do anything (there's no position -30 for Ç for example).
I need to figure how to get these values properly and send to the draw function.

Comment: I tried the wchar_t variable, but the values I get for these characters are pretty... offrange.

Comment: This has zero information. What is your OS? What is your compiler? What are you doing to print a character? What are you doing to display a character? What exactly have you tried with wchar_t?

Comment: This is most probably an encoding problem. Try to match the encoding of your source file, the encoding setting in your compiler, and the encoding used to identify the bitmaps from the font.

Comment: @nm Sorry, I didn't know they were relevant to the question... I'm clueless about how/why I can do this, hence the question. Edited with the informations.

Comment: "For these characters with accents, I'm getting negative values" cast them to an `unsigned` integral type, like `unsigned int` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: @DyP converting them to unsigned types worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: It works only if you have a single-byte encoding, so please watch out.

Comment: You're making a text editor, but have no idea about text encodings. It requires OpenGL but displays bitmapped glyphs. There better be a killer feature to redeem these shortcomings…

Comment: It's not really a text editor, it's a part of a game engine, so I need to be able to receive read a string from a binary file and output on screen as bitmap font. I've read about the unicode type formatting, but I don't have any way to generate a utf8 bitmap font, so I'm kinda stuck. But this has been very informative, and pointed me which way to go, so thanks again!

Comment: Pretty much any decent game engine works with Unicode encoded strings. You are not using an in-home made proprietary one, are you? There are many tools freely available which allow you to create fonts and bitmap font maps. Guess what? They are also Unicode aware. Sure you may go along with signed/unsigned hack but how far it'll take you? It is not that hard to set up a proper foundation using wchar_t type. You'll get compiler support, libraries support. You'll find it helpful in a future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Unicode**, it is year 2013 already :) [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You will use **wchar_t** as a type and **UTF-16 / UTF-32** encoding. That will make your code supporting not only "irregular" characters but many more "irregular" characters :) (there is no such a thing as regular characters).

**Example**

```
wchar_t c = L'Á';
printf("char: %lc encoding: %d\n", c, c);

c = 0xc1; 
printf("char: %lc encoding: %d\n", c, c);
```

**Output**

```
char: Á encoding: 193
char: Á encoding: 193
```

Comment: I agree, but he says that he already tried wchar and that he couldnt get it to work.... ;(

Comment: "Multi Byte to Unicode -- that doesn't make sense" It's an out-dated Windows terminology. Back in the old days, there were byte encodings similar to UTF-8 with multiple bytes per glyph/"code unit", and the "original" Unicode encoding was one 16-bit integer per code unit.