# Convert character to integer, and integer back to same character

Tags: c, unicode

I want two create two functions that can do this. So one function takes a character, for example the character `a` and returns the integer `97`. The other function takes this integer `97` and returns the character `a`. I know this can be done by using the ASCII codes of these characters, but then it wouldn't work for characters like `é, à, ö`. Can this be done using unicode or another way?

For example:

```
int character_to_integer(char c) {
    convert character to integer and return
}

Input: character_to_index('é');
Output: 102 (for example)

char integer_to_character(int i) {
    convert integer to character and return
}

Input: integer_to_character(102);
Output: é
```

I want to do this with it: have an  array, so for example `int my_array[5]` with all elements set to `NULL` at the start. Then for example, index 0, 3 and 4 (which correspond to a, d and e for example) are set to something other than `NULL` then I want to loop over it and build a string based off the which indexes aren't `NULL`, like so:

```
void build_string_from_array(int my_array) {
    char buffer[16];
    char c;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (my_array[i] != NULL) {
            c = integer_to_character(i);
            buffer[i] = c;
        }
    }
    buffer[5] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

Output: ade
```

Note, this is just an example, and I know there is probably something wrong with it, but it's just to get my point across. I know this can be done with ASCII codes, where all the characters are only 1 `char`, but how can this be done so that characters like `é`, that are seen as 2 `char`s would also work?

If it's not clear what I mean just ask me and I'll elaborate some more.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819861/c-string-char-and-accents).

Comment: Also since as you said an ascii character will do why do you want to use multiple characters for the representation?

Comment: C does not have a character type. `char` **is** and integer type. Solution in search of a problem?

Comment: @CarefulNow ASCII code works for characters like `a`, but not for characters like `á`.

Comment: @Mosbas I haven't implemented this but try this page for the codes. It is extended ascii so will not be supported natively by chars but you could implement it yourself  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-e-acute-accent-e-acute-lowercase-ascii-code-130.html

Comment: You need to know what *encoding* is being used to represent the accented characters. Probably UTF-8 since they're multi-byte, but C isn't trying to interpret those bytes so it doesn't care. If it is UTF-8 then you can convert to Unicode codepoints using code similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987).

Comment: Reference the Build String function - you are passing an int - but using it as a pointer to an int array - this needs to be a int* (?).

Answer (score 1):

For single Byte chars, this is no Problem, since char is a integer:

```
int i = 'B';
```

and

```
char c = 0x33;
```

will work fine.

But, if you use UTF8 with chars with more than one Byte, you must convert the UTF8-String to a UCS4 String. Sadly there is no Standard API for that.

See also this Post: [Converting a UTF-8 text to wchar_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120965/converting-a-utf-8-text-to-wchar-t)

A other way is use wchar_t everywhere. This will not work well on Windows with chars outside the BMP, since the wchar_t implementation in Windows is brocken (wchar_t is still a Multibyte Character Set on Windows). On Linux it will work, if you not use compound chars.